# How can I disable the revive utility pop up?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

Recently when I die, the Revive Utility automatically pops up on the screen for purchase. How do I turn this pop up off? My kids are using all my coins!

Comment: I don't think you can, other than give them a stern telling off every time they do that. It's not an IAP (no real money used), so parental controls won't work

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you can't disable that popup. There is no area to control a setting like that within game, or within settings of the operating system (iOS settings for example). It still shows up even if you don't have 1,500 coins, and allows you to purchase more coins.

Answer (score 0):

That popup only shows up on my game on Android device but not on Windows Phone 8 device. You should create new profile for your kids if you are using Android. Not sure if it works with other platforms.